# Does /etc/host.deny blocks http requests?

Tags: firewall, unix

If I put the entry into /etc/hosts.deny, would it block all requests from that IP address to my machine (like *iptables* do), or would it only block access for some applications like SSH?

Comment: What entry are you putting in the file?

Comment: This was my question, and I have got two good, useful answers. I tried some googling before but without particular success.

Comment: It might be what you wanted to know but that's not your question as written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about a standard linux distro, then it depends on the application. The question being about port 80, I'd be inclined to answer no, as most webservers I'm aware of (most notably, apache) are *not* compiled  against the tcpwrapper library - which is what makes applications aware of hosts.{allow,deny} directives.

Webservers have - of course - their own way of shutting out unwanted clients. If you do not want to depend on app-specific methods, however, a low level firewall (such as the mentioned iptables) is the surest way.

Answer (score 5):

Iain's Reading Manuals As A Service at your erm service ...

It depends

If you put

```
ALL: 192.0.2.1, example.com
```

It will block access to *ALL* suitably compiled services for the listed hosts.

If you put

```
sshd: 192.0.2.1, example.com
```

then access to *sshd* will be blocked for the listed hosts, providing the sshd has been suitably compiled.

For a service to take advantage of hosts.deny|hosts.allow, it has to be tcpwrapper aware, not all services are.

In general you and check to see if a service is tcpwrapper aware like by looking for libwrap in the output of ldd for the binary e.g.

```
ldd /usr/sbin/sshd | grep libwrap
libwrap.so.0 => /lib64/libwrap.so.0 (0x00007fae25ae7000)
```

so in this case sshd is tcpwrapper aware.